# how to create a void function in C to divide the number in half with integer division until the value is 1?

Tags: c

Write a C program that has a recursive function called half. The function has one integer input parameter. The function will continue to divide the number in half with integer division until the value is 1. Print out the value from each recursive call from least to greatest.  The function has the following prototype:

void half(int value);

i managed to write the function but the numbers started to print from the greatest to least value.

```
void half(int value){
  if(value>1){
    printf("%d\n", value);
    half(value/2);
    return;
  }else{
      printf("1");
  }
}

this was my function so far.
```

Comment: You're printing too early. If the value is > 1 call half(value / 2) and print value unconditionally at the end.

Comment: If you want your program to also work with negative values, you'll need a different test to end the recursion.

Comment: alexh14, "...  until the value is 1" --> what should happen if `value == 0`?  If `value < 0`?

Comment: Also know that while recursive functions can provide elegant solutions in some circumstances, if a procedural approach is available, it should be preferred due to the risk of StackOverflow if you recurse too many times.

Answer (score 2):

Simply move the recursive call to `half` before `printf` in order to print from least to greatest.

You can remove the `else` branch as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void half(int value)
{
    if (value > 1)
        half(value / 2);

    printf("%d\n", value);
}

int main(void)
{
    half(144);
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
4
9
18
36
72
144
```